# Using Flask to iterate over an array to input into a PyMongo search

Tags: python, arrays, flask, pymongo

I have an array, let's say this one:

```
[ObjectId('5feceb11b5ffb79d03df04a0'), ObjectId('600c1c83e5c06febfb7f8ab5'), ObjectId('5fe8f9227221766fa23707d0'), ObjectId('5fe995f93137252b3bb37bbe')]
```

From that, I would like to find each ObjectId's profile in a database.

So all I would need to do is something like this:

```
person = mongo.db.users.find_one({"username": **each ObjectId**})
```

Where each ObjectId is one of the ObjectId's in the array.

This way then:

```
person == user1; and
person == user9; and
person == user13; and
person == user16
```

From there, I can probably manage this in Jinja as a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple documents to be returned you
can also use [find()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method instead but as per your use case you might need to use `$in` operator that might slow down if your list is large but still it would be better if executed in batches saving round trips to db and for better performance.

Then make sure each element in your list has **bson** `ObjectId` type and not python `str`, if not you can type cast python `str` to bson `ObjectId` by importing
ObjectId

```
>>> from bson import ObjectId
>>> print(type(ObjectId('5e9dc0548a4617a55665624f')))
>>> <class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>
```

So after ensuring you have a list of `ObjectId`s, then you can query using `find` and `$in` as follows:

```
>>> users = [ObjectId('5e9dc0548a4617a55665624f'),ObjectId('5e9dc0a75db97122a193aa51')]
>>> q = collection.find({'username': { "$in": users}})
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually was just solving that this way now too. Thank you.